# Problems arising from the AOSP Android build

Tags: android-source, android-build

I am currently ubuntu 18.04 (lts) asop build in.But an unexpected problem is occurring and over and over again.This is something wrong?

It's my development environment.
Python - 2.7.17
openjdk - 8

```
$user@ubuntu:~/android_build$ source ./imx-p9.0.0_2.2.0-ga/imx_android_setup.sh
$user@ubuntu:~/android_build$ lunch aosp_arm-eng
$user@ubuntu:~/android_build$ make -j 9 2>&1 | tee build-log.txt
```

build-log.txt -->
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LsM_H1moCVVzyZ21Gm3SOV-x3OUlGYQm/view?usp=sharing

If you have any additional requirements, please write them down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing your log, it looks like some file is missing in the vendor/nxp directory

```
vendor/nxp/fsl_imx_omx/OpenMAXIL/src/component/common/UniaDecoder.h:21:10: fatal error: 'fsl_unia.h' file not found
#include "fsl_unia.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Please check the codebase whether fsl_unia.h is added properly.